# How can i delete options on plugin uninstallation?

Tags: plugins

I want to delete option from database when plugin uninstall. It's name is `test_option`. I am using this code but doesn't work. Where is problem?

```
function test_delete() {
    if( !current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) )
        return;
    check_admin_referer( 'bulk-plugins' );

    if( __FILE__ != WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN )
        return;

    delete_option( 'test_option' );
}

register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, 'test_delete' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the option to register your unistall hook during plugin activation.

```
function myplugin_activation_callback(){
    register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_uninstall_callback' );
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activation_callback' );

function myplugin_uninstall_callback(){

    //Perform your uninstall operations here 
    delete_option('test_option');

}
```

However, the simplest way is to use an `uninstall.php` file with the following codes:

```
if (!defined('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN')) {
    die;
}

//Perform your uninstall operations here 
delete_option('test_option');
```

It's not recommended to use both at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for response. But i don't understand how to use second way.

Comment: @bilimokur Sorry for replying late. Create a file called `uninstall.php` with the code within it and place the file inside the root directory of your plugin. That file will be automatically called and executed upon uninstalling the plugin.